# Describe constraints of a table/matrix with owl

Tags: owl, ontology, description-logic

Afaik. `Owl:cardinality` is used to restrict how many values can a specific property contain. I was wondering, is it possible to describe with cardinality that rows in the same table must have the same cell count?

Comment: Do you know the cardinality in advance?  You could say that Rows that belongTo instances of ThreeColumnTable have exactly three columns, but you couldn't count the number of columns at runtime and then say that all the rows must have that number.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor No, I don't know. I just want to describe a rule, that in a single table the column count is constant amongst rows. I don't know the exact value.

Comment: So, you won't be able to do this with cardinalities, I think, but if you do some sort of processing that associates each row with the number of columns in it, you can then say that "if a row has X columns, then its table has X columns", and then you can say that "tables have exactly 1 number of columns".  So, if one row has 5 columns, and another has 3, then the table will have 5 columns, and will have 3 columns, and that will be an inconsistency that you can detect with a reasoner.